# Create a new variable with an existing variable name in a data frame, filling it when matching a non NA value in each of the variable lists

Tags: r, na

I want to create a column - C - in dfABy with the name of the existing variables, when in the list A or B it is a "non NA" value. For example, my df is:

```
             >dfABy 
             A    B 
             56   NA  
             NA   45  
             NA   77  
             67   NA  
             NA   65
```

The result what I will attend is:

```
             > dfABy
             A    B   C
             56   NA  A
             NA   45  B
             NA   77  B
             67   NA  A
             NA   65  B
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option using `dplyr` could be:

```
df %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(C = names(.[!is.na(c_across(everything()))]))

      A     B C    
  <int> <int> <chr>
1    56    NA A    
2    NA    45 B    
3    NA    77 B    
4    67    NA A    
5    NA    65 B
```

Or with the addition of `purrr`:

```
df %>%
    mutate(C = pmap_chr(across(A:B), ~ names(c(...)[!is.na(c(...))])))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked using the "purr" package. It is good because you can delimit the variables you want/need. Imagine if it was an additional column H...but you only want to create C column with what we have in A and B

Answer (score 2):

You can use `max.col` over `is.na` values to get the column numbers where non-NA value is present. From those numbers you can get the column names.

```
dfABy$C <- names(dfABy)[max.col(!is.na(dfABy))] 
dfABy

#   A  B C
#1 56 NA A
#2 NA 45 B
#3 NA 77 B
#4 67 NA A
#5 NA 65 B
```

If there are more than one non-NA value in a row take a look at at `ties.method` argument in `?max.col` on how to handle ties.

**data**

```
dfABy <- structure(list(A = c(56L, NA, NA, 67L, NA), B = c(NA, 45L, 77L, 
NA, 65L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Maybe add `first` like: `names(dfABy)[max.col(!is.na(dfABy), "first")]` to prevent returning a `C` when using it twice (as shown in your answer).

Comment: Yes, I actually ran it twice and got `C` as output. Fixed the output.

Answer (score 1):

Using the data.table package I recommend:

```
dfABy[, C := apply(cbind(dfABy), 1, function(x) names(x[!is.na(x)]))]
```

creating the following output:

```
    A   B   C
1   56  NA  A
2   NA  45  B
3   NA  77  B
4   67  NA  A
5   NA  65  B
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just another solution, However other proposed solutions are better.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(C = detect_index(c(A, B), ~ !is.na(.x)), 
         C = names(.[C]))

# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Rowwise: 
      A     B C    
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1    56    NA A    
2    NA    45 B    
3    NA    77 B    
4    67    NA A    
5    NA    65 B
```